# Failed to parse 'usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml'

Tags: package-management

Got this error during installation of `gnuradio`.  I also got this:

```
usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found.
```

Should I be concerned?  Everything else completes without errors.

Comment: `head -n3 /usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml`  edit your question for the output.

Comment: My apologies, but I fail to parse the comment.

Answer (score 3):

1. Delete `/usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml`.
2. Symlink `gnuradio-grc.xml` to `gnuradio.xml`:

   ```
   sudo ln -s gnuradio-grc.xml gnuradio.xml
   ```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu. Please provide some explanation, why the deleting and symlink creation is needed.

Comment: /usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml contains a single line "/usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio-grc.xml". Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Installation process failed to create a symlink.

Comment: Please "edit" your answer and add the explanation

Answer (score 1):

#### Error Message

```
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
/usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/freedesktop/gnuradio-grc.xml
^
Failed to parse '/usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml'
patrick@Aspire1:~$ ls -al /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/freedesktop/gnuradio-grc.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 265 Feb 27  2017 /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/freedesktop/gnuradio-grc.xml
```

The error message calls out the file, the line number (':1:') then shows the erroneous input on the next line (which is actually the full content (i.e. the only line) of the file) and points out the place where things went wrong with a '^'.

Analysis

- Linux is trying to update the mime type database with a new entry for objects associated with gnuradio using XML-format data provided by the gqrx install packages
- for reasons known only to themselves, the package maintainers provide the data in /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/freedesktop/gnuradio *-grc* .xml while the mime update utility is looking for /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/freedesktop/gnuradio.xml (N.B. NO '-grc') instead pointing to the XML by placing the *-grc.xml file name in the *.xml file and expecting update-mime-database to just figure it out.
- update-mime-database throws the error message which kills the apt install process

This can be replicated by manually updating the mime database as follows:

```
sudo update-mime-database -V /usr/share/mime/
Updating MIME database in /usr/share/mime...

/usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/freedesktop/gnuradio-grc.xml
^
Failed to parse '/usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml'
Wrote 1108 strings at 2c - 61d4

Wrote aliases at 61d4 - 6a40

Wrote parents at 6a40 - 82e4

Wrote literal globs at 82e4 - 83cc

Wrote suffix globs at 83cc - 130b4

Wrote full globs at 130b4 - 1310c

Wrote magic at 1310c - 1f7a8

Wrote namespace list at 1f7a8 - 1f8e4

Wrote icons list at 1f8e4 - 1f8e8

Wrote generic icons list at 1f8e8 - 204d4

Wrote types list at 204d4 - 21130
```

Resolution

1. the contents of gnuradio.xml are bad so get rid of it
   2.  `sudo rm /usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml`
2. the contents of gnuradio-grc.xml are what's needed so link it
   4. `sudo ln -s /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/freedesktop/gnuradio-grc.xml /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/freedesktop/gnuradio.xml`
3. test `sudo update-mime-database -V /usr/share/mime/`

`Updating MIME database in /usr/share/mime...`

`Wrote 1108 strings at 2c - 61d4`

`Wrote aliases at 61d4 - 6a40`

`Wrote parents at 6a40 - 82e4`

`Wrote literal globs at 82e4 - 83cc`

`Wrote suffix globs at 83cc - 130b4`

`Wrote full globs at 130b4 - 1310c`

`Wrote magic at 1310c - 1f7a8`

`Wrote namespace list at 1f7a8 - 1f8e4`

`Wrote icons list at 1f8e4 - 1f8e8`

`Wrote generic icons list at 1f8e8 - 204d4`

`Wrote types list at 204d4 - 21130`

Manually instructing apt and/or dpkg to continue from here may be required. This is unlikely to hurt anything in any case.

```
sudo apt-get -f install

    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nano /usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml
```

Go to the first row and make sure it begins with an `<`

```
sudo update-mime-database -V /usr/share/mime/
```

This updates the mime database.